# INDIRECT inside INDEX function giving #REF error

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-indirect

I'm have an excel workbook **Spreadsheet.xlsx** in which **B2**`=MATCH(B1,'\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$500,0)` takes the string (a name) in in **B1** and matches it to a column of row headers in **Workbook.xlsx**, to give the row number.

Currently **B2** returns a value of **8**, which is used in **B3**`=INDEX('\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$8:$SD$8), MATCH($A4,'\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$SD$2,0))`.

**B3** indexes a range of values `$A$8:$SD$8` corresponding to the row number from **B2** in **Sheet1** in **Workbook.xlsx**, and returns the values matched to a date `$A4` in the range `$A$2:$SD$2`.

Currently I am manually typing in the row number to **B3** range `$A$8:$SD$8.

If I try to automate this using **B3**`=INDEX(INDIRECT("'\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$"&B2&":$SD$"&B2), MATCH($A4,'\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$SD$2,0))`, I get a `#REF` error.

I have used `INDIRECT` elsewhere e.g. `=MAX(INDIRECT(K&"K1"))` and it has worked just fine.
Also, **Workbook.xlsx** and **Sheet1** in it definitely exist, and I am able to get data from them without using `INDIRECT`.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure what is the problem, but does the formula work if `Workbook.xlsx` is open when you calculate it? It's a function that doesn't work if the file it references is closed, but then, `INDEX` and `MATCH` are as well, so I just wanted to confirm by ruling this out. Another thing that might be a typo, is that you have the first part of `INDEX` referring to a sheet named 'Sheet' which you didn't mention anywhere else.

Comment: @Jerry The problem is that my formulae work correctly seperately, but when I try to pipe the result from one cell into another using `INDIRECT`, it doesn't work. If I enter the value of **B2** manually into the range referenced by INDEX, it works fine; if I use `INDIRECT` to input the number from **B2** into **B3**, it doesn't work. Also, yes it does work when `Workbook.xlsx` is open alongside, and then doesn't when it is closed. Thanks for spotting the typo, fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INDEX` and `MATCH` functions, as used here, **do** work with closed workbooks - `INDIRECT` **doesn't**

...but you don't really need `INDIRECT` here - you can use this version with `B2` defining the row number in the first range

`=INDEX('\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$SD$500),B2, MATCH($A4,'\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$SD$2,0))`

That should work even if the source workbook is closed, and is a "cleaner", more robust approach in any case.

Note that the first range in the formula is changed to be as long as your match range from B2

If you want you can cut out B2 altogether, just put the MATCH function from B2 in that formula *in place* of B2, i.e.

`=INDEX('\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$SD$500),MATCH(B1,'\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$500,0), MATCH($A4,'\\SERVER\Path\To\File\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$SD$2,0))`

[Note: as Jerry mentioned, your sheet names weren't consistent so I changed the first to **Sheet1** to match the others]

Comment: Thank you very much, this works exactly as I wanted it to and cuts out an entire row of useless cells! Also, thanks for spotting the typo, fixed it now.